# Matching query does not exist error

Tags: python, django, database

There are a bunch of people on this site have had a similar questions to mine, but I can't seem to find one that has solved it the way I want it to.

I'm trying to get a password out of a database so that I can send an email automatically. To do this, I am calling `Credential.objects.get(username='foo').password`.
This is where I get the error.
What's really weird about this is I already had access to this database in a python console, ***and*** I've created a row in it. I have no clue why it's not showing up!

Other people seem to recommend doing the following:

```
try:
    Credential.objects.get(username='foo').password
except Exception as e:
    return None
```

All that this is doing is making sure the program doesn't return an error.
**This doesn't help me because this can't fail.**
An email must be sent and this call must get it.
I'm almost certain I'm calling the right function for this, but I've been wrong before. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

---

credential.py (not putting up `max_length` for security reasons):

```
import d_models as models

class Credential(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField()
    password = EncryptedCharField()
```

---

Comment: first thing, models.CharField(), it must need max_length as argument, If you'll not give to field, project will not run.

Comment: Could you print Exception using *try:
    Credential.objects.get(username='foo').password
except Exception as e: print(e)
    return None*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two hours of looking at my code, I realized that I am an idiot.

One thing that I left out was that I ran this function in a test case, which spins up separate blank test databases. The function call wouldn't work because it was trying to get at the wrong database!

To fix this I just called: `./manage.py dumpdata --format json --indent 4 -o ./full/path/to/file/credential.json` and put `fixtures = ['./full/path/to/file/credential.json']` at the top of the test class. Thanks to everyone for the suggestions! Hopefully I didn't waste too much of your time!

Answer (score 0):

Following may clear your concept.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    Credential.objects.get(username='foo').password
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
#If User with username='foo' does not exist in database then it will comes #in exception.
#Even if there are multiple entries in database with username='foo' then also it will give you error for this you need to use another exception. 
    return "What ever you want to return on exception"
```

Or else you can try:

```
python manage.py shell
for user in Credentials.objects.all():
    print username
    print password
```

And check what are the users are available in your database(configured in settings.py file).